# How to verify the equality in two arrayList with Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin

In my android app, with kotlin. 
I have two arrayList "productsToBuy" contains the list of product to buy,"variantArrayList": contains the variant list.
The product to buy could have either product or variant,Here, I would like to know if the variant id in the list products to buy.I want to get the Id or a boolean attribute as result.
So, How can I verify the equality between this two arraylist with the Id. The following code is my essay, I know is a incorrect code but how can I correct it to get what I want and why is incorrect

```
    for (i in 0 until variantArrayList.size) {
        val tempVariant = StreamSupport.stream(productsToBuy)
                .filter { o1 -> o1.id.equals(variantArrayList[i].id) }
                .collect(Collectors.toList<PurchaseItemsData>())
        if (tempVariant.size != 0) {
            variantPurchaseItem = true
            break
        }
    }
```

Comment: does it provide the desired result ?

Comment: no, it doesn't provide the desired result

Comment: So you want to check whether particular item in product buy list is available in variant list if present return the item id or something?. Am I correct >

Comment: yes, exactly that's what I want

Answer (score 0):

```
productsToBuy.map { it.id }.intersect(variantArrayList.map { it.id }).isNotEmpty()
```

The above statement will check if `productsToBuy` contains `variantArrayList` based on `id`
and returns `Boolean`. If you want to get only ids you can simply remove `isNotEmpty()`

Since we are only making sure if `productsToBuy` contains any of the item from `variantArrayList`, we can also try like this. This will also consider the ids being `null`.

```
val variantProduct = productsToBuy.asSequence()
        .firstOrNull { product -> variantArrayList.any { product.id == it.id } }
variantPurchaseItem = variantProduct != null
```

Comment: This ansewr return an exception as result, I will edit my post with a new code 
Please give me your opinion about it

Comment: Make sure ids are not null